# Three-layered approach in PHP

Tags: java, php, three-tier

I liked using three layers (data/business logic|services/ui) in Java and wish to apply this to a web site in PHP. What advice, links, tutorials could you suggest in this respect?

P.S: I'm particularly interested in knowing how the domain/entity objects can be written and used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could go with some frameworks of PHP.

They already done three layer for you

[ZendFramework](http://framework.zend.com/)

[CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/)

This could be interesting for you and help you to choose right framework.

[PHPFrameworks](http://www.phpframeworks.com/)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a PHP framework that actually follows the Model View Controll (MVC) pattern then you will need to look at [Agavi](http://www.agavi.org). Many other frameworks have attempted to implement it but have failed.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I am wrong, but this is an MVC approach ([Model->View->Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller))?

If so, checkout a framework like [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/), they have a pretty good learning zone for you.

Comment: It's similar in that some separation/decoupling is sought. The main difference is that the view can't communicate directly with the data layer (and vice versa) and must go through the logic layer. Also, the domain classes which I forgot to mention can be considered as equivalent to the model. It can be combined with MVC.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the [MVC](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller-model) pattern used in many frameworks for PHP.

You could use frameworks like [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org), [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/), [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/), [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/), which all uses this pattern.

MVC stands for Model-View-Controller, where the model contains the business logic, the view contains the UI, and the controller handles the requests and ties things together.

Answer (score 1):

Symfony (http://www.symfony-project.org/) gets good reviews from my PHP slinging mates